# Elastic Kubernetes Service AWS Deployment process to avoid down time

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Its been a month I have started working on EKS AWS and up till now successfully deployed by code.
The steps which I follow for deployment are given below:

1. Create image from docker terminal.
2. Tag and push to ECR AWS.
3. Create the deployment **"project.json"** and service file **"project-svc.json"**.
4. Save the above file in **"kubectl/bin"** path and deploy it with following commands below.
5. `"kubectl apply -f projectname.json"` and `"kubectl apply -f projectname-svc.json"`.
6. So if I want to deployment the same project again with change, I push the new image on ECR and delete the existing deployment by using `"kubectl delete -f projectname.json"` without deleting the existing service and deploy it again using command `"kubectl apply -f projectname.json"` again.

Now, I'm in confusing that after I delete the existing deployment there is a downtime until I apply or create the deployment again. So, how to avoid this ? Because I don't want the downtime actually that is the reason why I started to use the EKS. 
And one more thing is the process of deployment is a bit long too. I know I'm missing something can anybody guide me properly please?

The project is on .NET Core and if there is any simplified way to do deployment using Visual Studio please guide me for that also.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the delete/apply if you are changing (And if you have) the ConfigMap attached to the Deployment.
Is the only change you do is the "image" of the deployment - you must use the "set-image" command.

Kubectl let you change the actual deployment image and it does the Rolling Updates all by itself and with 3+ pods you have the minimum chance for downtime.
Even more, if you use the --record flag, you can "rollback" to your previous image with no effort because it keep track of the changes.

You also have the possibility to specify the "Context" too, with no need to jump from contexts.

You can go like this:

> **kubectl set image deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME DEPLOYMENT_NAME=IMAGE_NAME --record -n NAMESPACE**

OR *Specifying the Cluster*

> **kubectl set image deployment DEPLOYEMTN_NAME DEPLOYEMTN_NAME=IMAGE_NAME_ECR -n NAMESPACE --cluster EKS_CLUSTER_NPROD --user EKS_CLUSTER --record**

As an Eg:

```
kubectl set image deployment nginx-dep nginx-dep=ecr12345/nginx:latest -n nginx --cluster eu-central-123-prod --user eu-central-123-prod --record
```

The --record is what let you track all the changes, if you want to rollback just do:

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment.v1.apps/nginx-dep
```

More documentations about it here:

**Updating a deployment**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment

**Roll Back Deployment**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment

Comment: Thank you for your response actually I'm bit confuse that which one is the deployment name in Json file ? `apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80`

Comment: I hope you understood my concern... In above command I don;t know which in my deployment file is DEPLOYMENT_NAME, NAMESPACE and IMAGE_NAME_ECR should be full path or e.g ABC_IMAGE:LATEST (with tag?) ? Thank you

Comment: I receive this error "Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "my-project" not found"

Comment: The name is the name: of you deployment,  name: nginx-deployment

Comment: `kubectl get deployment` respose "No resources found." but my deployment is working fine from last 18 days.

Comment: The image is like: myrepo/myimage:mytag

Comment: Ok.. the first time you deploy you must do the apply of the file.. the set image is used after that... to manage that deployment without another apply or delete.. and as a said on the answer,  its good to use this if the only thing you want to change is the image itself... is you need to change a port for example, tou must do the apply or delete apply..

Comment: ya I only want to change image nothing else. I got it but I cannot find any deployment if I run `kubectl get deployment` as mention above. So I'm confuse what will be the deployment name in this case.

Comment: If you cannot find deployments is because you did not applied any of them.. like kubectl apply -f path/for/deployment.json

Comment: so now is there any way around that i can update it without path/deployment ? Or I need to deploy everything again ? Along with its service ? The problem is if i will deploy service it will change the URLs also. Secondly, I want to ask that only if deploy like this "deployment_project/project.json" it will automatically create deployment with name of "deployment_project" ?

Comment: You can have services in different files from the deployment it self, you can apply the service once and never touch it again if you want.

No the deployment name is specified on the "name:" parameter inside json or yaml.
The official docs guides you.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no need to delete your deployment. Just need to update the desired state (the deployment configuration) and let K8s do its magic and apply the needed changes, like deploying a new version of your container.

If you have a single instance of your container, you will experience a short down time while changes are applied. If your application supports multiple replicas (HA), you can enjoy the rolling upgrade feature.

Start by reading the official Kubernetes documentation of a [Performing a Rolling Update.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/)

Comment: I tried this before also but confuse that which one in my deployment file is DEPLOYMENT_NAME, NAMESPACE and IMAGE_NAME should be full url or only tag (e.g latest)?

Comment: `kubectl get deployment` respose "No resources found." but my deployment is working fine from last 18 days.